# Windows Azure cloud service and RDLC report loading error

Tags: azure-diagnostics

I have hosted an MVC application in Window Azure as Cloud Service. I use RDLC reporting service for reporting. Each first time with some short intervals, when I call my RDLC report, It ends up in Server error. A refresh would solve the issue and report gets loaded just fine. Is it a problem with the Environment? Any one faced such issues? What can fix this issue? Error details given below:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:
>
> 1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

> or:
>
> 2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:
>
> Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.
>
> Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.]
>      System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>      System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +525
>      System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +19
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +315
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) +208
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +1171
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +146
>      System.Web.UI.AssemblyCache.GetAjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute(Assembly assembly) +103
>      System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_DefaultAjaxFrameworkAssembly() +592
>      System.Web.UI.ScriptManager..ctor() +30
>      ASP.rdlcs_viewreport_aspx.__BuildControlform1() +202
>      ASP.rdlcs_viewreport_aspx.FrameworkInitialize() +193
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +72
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +269
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +167
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +664
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270

Comment: I have done this in azure. First is important to know that in the free usage you can't use a 64-bit compiled website, so check if your build configuration is in X86 or X64. Also you need to make sure to mark the references 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common', 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel', 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms' as "Copy Local" set to 'true'. I have to do this with other references in the project that doesn't 'live' in the Azure environment. Hope it helps!

Comment: Still I face this problem

Answer (score 0):

Configure you Azure Cloud Service to run under operating systems such as "Windows Server 2012 or above" which has .NET 4.5 in built.

[image]